# how to create two rows of icons in menu page

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, row

I have made a row of menu icons,  i was wondering if it was possible to create the the same row of icons in a row underneath.

This is the html i already have for the top row of icons :

```
<body>

<div id="demo"</div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>

</body>
```

And this is the Css:

```
nav ul {list-style: none; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
nav ul li {float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 0;}
nav ul li a {display: block; width: 120px; height: 120px;background-image:            url(icons.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;}
nav ul li:nth-child(1) a {background-color: #5bb2fc;background-position: 28px 28px;}
nav ul li:nth-child(2) a {background-color: #58ebd3;background-position: 28px -96px;}
nav ul li:nth-child(3) a {background-color: #ffa659;background-position: 28px -222px;}
nav ul li:nth-child(4) a {background-color: #ff7a85;background-position: 28px -342px;}
nav ul li:nth-child(5) a {background-color: #3FC;background-position: 28px -342px;}
nav ul li a span {font: 50px "Dosis", sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;position: absolute; left: 600px; top: 29px;display: none;}
nav ul li a:hover span {display: block;}
nav ul li:nth-child(1) a span {color: #5bb2fc;}
nav ul li:nth-child(2) a span {color: #58ebd3;}
nav ul li:nth-child(3) a span {color: #ffa659;}
nav ul li:nth-child(4) a span {color: #ff7a85;}
nav ul li:nth-child(5) a span {color: #ff7a85;}
```

Comment: Just add another nav ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, add another UL under the one you already have

```
<body>

<div id="demo"</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

</body>
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7PLT/

Comment: Glad I could help! I'd appreciate if you accepted my answer if it's working for you.